# zurb foundation: tooltip reflow really slow on IE, FF

Tags: internet-explorer, zurb-foundation, internet-explorer-11

I've got some JavaScript on a page that adds a lot of tooltips dynamically.  It works pretty quick.  Problem is that I need to call `$(document).foundation("tooltip", "reflow")` to have the tooltips display correctly, but the function is excruciatingly slow on IE11 (slow on FF, too).

Anyway to speed this up?  Can I call reflow on individual tooltips as needed, for example?

Comment: tried a setTimeout(..., 0) call, but the page is 'locked up' while the reflow is happening.

Comment: Did you see the network request on developer toolbar to look for the issue request ?

Comment: Having the exact same issue!  One thing to note... there's no slow downs when using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a bug in foundation.  Something they're considering on fixing in the next release (6+).
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6092

Answer (score 0):

@TwiceB: In your link, the solution is to patch the foundation code:

```
.on('DOMNodeRemoved DOMAttrModified', '[' + this.attr_name() + ']:not(a)', function (e) {
          self.hide(S(this));
        });
```

remove DOMAttrModified and IE & FF are responsive again.